# How to disable Scrolling if not clicked on Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a *Cookie Banner* and struggling with the following:
As soon as a new user visits the page, the Cookie Banner loads and disables scrolling.

I tried different ways with jQuery, JS and CSS `body { overflow: hidden }` but none of them worked. I don't know how to disable scrolling as long as the user hasn't clicked on "Accept". Does anyone have ideas?

My idea is something like:

```
onload - show cookie Banner 

if not clicked on "accept"
    overflow: hidden;
else
    default scrolling experience
```

Comment: Once you have disabled the scrolling, what will prevent the user from pressing F12, removing your banner and re-enable scrolling manually? Or isn't that an issue? Just asking because if it is something you have to account for, might as well capture that issue immediately as well.

Comment: @Shilly I doubt he needs to go that hardcore for a cookie banner...

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your issue:

```
$(document ).ready(function() {
    let body = $('html, body')

    // when the document is ready disable page scrolling by default
    body.css('overflow', 'hidden');

    // when click on your banner button enable page scrolling
    $('#your-button-id-here').click(()=>
        body.css('overflow', 'auto'); 
    ) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have full control of how you structure your HTML document, you can do it with pure CSS, no JavaScript required.

The trick is to create a checkbox `input` element to store the state of the notice (hidden or visible). You then use a label for that input as the button the user clicks to accept. When the user clicks the label, the checkbox is checked, and you can use `:checked` selectors to hide the notice and re-enable scrolling on your content wrapper.

The main requirement for this to work is that you can make the `input` element a sibling of your scrollable content wrapper, and have it appear before the wrapper in your HTML markup.

Note that you'll probably need to do some extra work to make the pseudo-button accessible for screen readers, keyboards, etc.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: .8em;
}

.notice-content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #daedf3;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 300ms;
}

.notice-content label {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: .2em .4em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.notice-overlay {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 300ms;
}

.content {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: .5em;
}

#notice-accepted {
  display: none;
}

#notice-accepted:checked ~ .notice .notice-content,
#notice-accepted:checked ~ .notice .notice-overlay {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#notice-accepted:not(:checked) ~ .content {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input id="notice-accepted" type="checkbox" />

<div class="notice">
    <div class="notice-content">
        Please accept cookies...
        <label for="notice-accepted">Accept</label>
    </div>
    <div class="notice-overlay"></div>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <p>Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water spinach avocado daikon napa cabbage asparagus winter purslane kale. Celery potato scallion desert raisin horseradish spinach carrot soko. Lotus root water spinach fennel kombu maize bamboo shoot green bean swiss chard seakale pumpkin onion chickpea gram corn pea. Brussels sprout coriander water chestnut gourd swiss chard wakame kohlrabi beetroot carrot watercress. Corn amaranth salsify bunya nuts nori azuki bean chickweed potato bell pepper artichoke.</p>
    <p>Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water spinach avocado daikon napa cabbage asparagus winter purslane kale. Celery potato scallion desert raisin horseradish spinach carrot soko. Lotus root water spinach fennel kombu maize bamboo shoot green bean swiss chard seakale pumpkin onion chickpea gram corn pea. Brussels sprout coriander water chestnut gourd swiss chard wakame kohlrabi beetroot carrot watercress. Corn amaranth salsify bunya nuts nori azuki bean chickweed potato bell pepper artichoke.</p>
    <p>Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water spinach avocado daikon napa cabbage asparagus winter purslane kale. Celery potato scallion desert raisin horseradish spinach carrot soko. Lotus root water spinach fennel kombu maize bamboo shoot green bean swiss chard seakale pumpkin onion chickpea gram corn pea. Brussels sprout coriander water chestnut gourd swiss chard wakame kohlrabi beetroot carrot watercress. Corn amaranth salsify bunya nuts nori azuki bean chickweed potato bell pepper artichoke.</p>
    <p>Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water spinach avocado daikon napa cabbage asparagus winter purslane kale. Celery potato scallion desert raisin horseradish spinach carrot soko. Lotus root water spinach fennel kombu maize bamboo shoot green bean swiss chard seakale pumpkin onion chickpea gram corn pea. Brussels sprout coriander water chestnut gourd swiss chard wakame kohlrabi beetroot carrot watercress. Corn amaranth salsify bunya nuts nori azuki bean chickweed potato bell pepper artichoke.</p>
    <p>Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water spinach avocado daikon napa cabbage asparagus winter purslane kale. Celery potato scallion desert raisin horseradish spinach carrot soko. Lotus root water spinach fennel kombu maize bamboo shoot green bean swiss chard seakale pumpkin onion chickpea gram corn pea. Brussels sprout coriander water chestnut gourd swiss chard wakame kohlrabi beetroot carrot watercress. Corn amaranth salsify bunya nuts nori azuki bean chickweed potato bell pepper artichoke.</p>
    <p>Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water spinach avocado daikon napa cabbage asparagus winter purslane kale. Celery potato scallion desert raisin horseradish spinach carrot soko. Lotus root water spinach fennel kombu maize bamboo shoot green bean swiss chard seakale pumpkin onion chickpea gram corn pea. Brussels sprout coriander water chestnut gourd swiss chard wakame kohlrabi beetroot carrot watercress. Corn amaranth salsify bunya nuts nori azuki bean chickweed potato bell pepper artichoke.</p>
    <p>Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water spinach avocado daikon napa cabbage asparagus winter purslane kale. Celery potato scallion desert raisin horseradish spinach carrot soko. Lotus root water spinach fennel kombu maize bamboo shoot green bean swiss chard seakale pumpkin onion chickpea gram corn pea. Brussels sprout coriander water chestnut gourd swiss chard wakame kohlrabi beetroot carrot watercress. Corn amaranth salsify bunya nuts nori azuki bean chickweed potato bell pepper artichoke.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way I would suggest is to add/remove a class on `html` and `body` using `jQuery` like below:

```
$('html,body').addClass('noscroll');
```

Remove this class whenever/wherever you need.

And, in your CSS, add the below code:

```
html.noscroll,body.noscroll{
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
```

Now, it is upto you when you want to enable/disable the document scrolling.